# Consolidating Facet with Donut Plots

Tags: r, plotly

I am attempting to combine two Donut plots into one figure. I am encountering an issue because each plot has its own legend, and I would like to have a single legend displayed on the right side of both plots, rather than having one common legend for both.

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

# data
mtcars$manuf <- sapply(strsplit(rownames(mtcars), " "), "[[", 1)
df <- mtcars %>% 
      group_by(am, manuf) %>% 
      summarize(count = n())

# Donut 1
fig1 <- plot_ly(df %>% 
                  count(am, manuf) %>% 
                  filter(am == 0), labels = ~manuf, values = ~n, type = 'pie', hole = 0.6,
                domain = list(x = c(0, 0.48), y = c(0, 1))) %>%
        layout(
          title = "Donut Chart 1",
          showlegend = FALSE,
          xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
          yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE)
        )

# Donut 2
fig2 <- plot_ly(df %>% 
                  count(am, manuf) %>% 
                  filter(am == 1),
                  labels = ~manuf, values = ~n, type = 'pie', hole = 0.6,
                domain = list(x = c(0.52, 1), y = c(0, 1))) %>%
        layout(
          title = "Donut Chart 2",
          showlegend = TRUE,
          xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
          yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE)
        )

facet_fig <- subplot(fig1, fig2, nrows = 1, shareX = TRUE, shareY = TRUE, titleX = FALSE, titleY = FALSE)
facet_fig
```

This code produce figure as figure shown below.
[image]

As you can see legend is right for both, instead each of them to have separate legend. Can any body help me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Does it need to be plotly?

Comment: @Allan Cameron Yes in Plotly

Comment: What was wrong with using subplot from your previous question?

Comment: @Dave2e See where is legend. I need to have legend on from right side of each Donut plot